# New mdframed environment with section numbering

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

Could you please help me with the following problem.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \def\mdf@mytitle{}
    \define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
      \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}

    \mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}

    \tikzset{
    excursus line/.style={%
    line width=2pt,
draw=gray!40,
rounded corners=2ex,
},
excursus head/.style={%
fill=white,
font=\bfseries\sffamily,
text=blue!80,
anchor=base west,
},
}
\mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
singleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
\path [excursus line]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
($(Q)+(30em,0ex)$);
%\node at ($(M)$) {M};
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
firstextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,-to]
(O) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-2pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
secondextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,round cap-]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
middleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow]
(O) -- (Q);},
middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
hidealllines=true,topline=true,
innertopmargin=0.5ex,
innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innerleftmargin=2ex,
skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
}

    \makeatother

\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}{section}[section]

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{test}

\begin{df}
    TEXT!!!
\end{df}

\begin{df}
    TEXT 2!
\end{df}

\end{document}
```

I would like to number all the definitions like Definition 1.1, Definition 1.2 and so on. But i don't know how to do it correctly. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Best regards

tech.

PS: I'm new in stackexchange, so please apologize my coding in here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add the part before `\begin{document}` that makes the document compilable?

Comment: Would answers with `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed` also welcome?

Comment: There you go, egreg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcounter{mydef}[section]
\renewcommand\themydef{\arabic{section}.\arabic{mydef}}

\makeatletter
    \def\mdf@mytitle{}
    \define@key{mdf}{mytitle}{%
      \def\mdf@mytitle{#1}}

    \mdf@do@stringoption{digressiontitle=={Digression}}

    \tikzset{
    excursus line/.style={%
    line width=2pt,
draw=gray!40,
rounded corners=2ex,
},
excursus head/.style={%
fill=white,
font=\bfseries\sffamily,
text=blue!80,
anchor=base west,
},
}
\mdfdefinestyle{digressionarrows}{%
extra={\stepcounter{mydef}},%
singleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path let \p1=(Q), \p2=(O) in (\x1,{(\y1-\y2)/2}) coordinate (M);
\path [excursus line]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (M) |- %
($(Q)+(30em,0ex)$);
%\node at ($(M)$) {M};
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
firstextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,-to]
(O) |- %
($(Q)+(12em,0ex)$) .. controls +(0:16em) and +(185:6em) .. %
++(23em,2ex);
%\node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-2pt)$) {Digression};},
\ifx\empty\mdf@mytitle\empty
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef};
\else
   \node [excursus head] at ($(Q)+(2.5em,-0.75pt)$) {\mdf@digressiontitle~\themydef:\space\mdf@mytitle};
\fi},
secondextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow,round cap-]
($(O)+(5em,0ex)$) -| (Q);},
middleextra={%
\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in (\x2,\y1) coordinate (Q);
\path [excursus arrow]
(O) -- (Q);},
middlelinewidth=2.5em,middlelinecolor=white,
hidealllines=true,topline=true,
innertopmargin=0.5ex,
innerbottommargin=2.5ex,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innerleftmargin=2ex,
skipabove=0.87\baselineskip,
skipbelow=0.62\baselineskip,
}
\makeatother

\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{test}

\begin{df}
test text
\end{df}

\begin{df}
test text
\end{df}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Basically, all you had to do was to create a counter, prepend the `section` counter to it and use it after the header. The line

```
\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}{section}[section]
```

should have been

```
\newmdenv[style=digressionarrows,digressiontitle=Definition]{df}
```

Using [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), however, your code looks simpler:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
mybox/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colframe=white,
  coltitle=white,
  coltitle=blue,
  colback=white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  frame code={},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=20pt},
  boxed title style={colback=white,frame code={},bottom=0pt,boxsep=0pt},
  overlay unbroken={
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40] (title.south east) -- ([xshift=-43pt]frame.east|-title.south east);
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40,rounded corners=2ex] 
    (title.south west) -| (frame.south west) -- ([xshift=50pt]frame.south west);
  },
  overlay first={
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40] (title.south east) -- ([xshift=-43pt]frame.east|-title.south east);
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40,rounded corners=2ex] 
    (title.south west) -| (frame.south west);
  },
    overlay middle={
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40] (frame.north west) -- (frame.south west);
  },
  overlay last={
    \draw[line width=2pt,gray!40,rounded corners=2ex] 
    (frame.north west) -| (frame.south west) -- ([xshift=50pt]frame.south west);
  }
 }
}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{tcbdf}{
  mybox,
  title=Definition~\thetcbcounter.\arabic{section}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{test}

\begin{tcbdf}
test text
\end{tcbdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tcolorbox solutions are also welcome, of course.

Comment: @Tech You're welcome! I added to my answer the translation of the original code to `tcolorbox`, in case you are interested in switching.

Comment: Could you explain why there is an overlay middle and an overlay last? Or in the mdframed example: why do i need those second extra and middle extra and stuff? I haven't quite understood that.

Comment: I have also defined some "new" theorems with

Comment: @Tech because is a box has a page break, the fframe bahaves differently on the first part (where it begins), the last part (where it ends) and possibly in the middle part (pages in the middle). If page breaks are present, the first part should have the ending curve; the last part shouldn't have the title and the initial lines, etc. So you need to control the look of the box for the initial, last and middle parts.

Comment: **Code** \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition} </code> How can I use the same counter as in the mdframed definitions?  And how do you format the code in here? Do I really need to go to every line and type 4 spaces there?

Comment: And there is another thing i would like to add in the mdframed Definition and in the theorems. It would be nice if i could do a quote there with the cite command of bibtex. Also i would like to add a title there: Something like "Definition 1.1 (Pythagorean Theorem) [Pyth03, Definition 6]".

Comment: @Tech Sorry. Too many new questions that were not in the original post; this is not how this site works. We like to keep this, if possible, as one question per post. Please feel free to open a fresh new question with those new requirements; make sure you mention all of them from the beginning; otherwise, it's a waste of time to be editing answers.